# AngularJS: access json response in link function inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going to use a chart library called Plotly. I'm creating a directive so I can use the library with angularJS and reuse in the future if needed.

I want to pass to the directive a object that will be used to create the graph. This objects is loaded through a call. Here's the code:

CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module("app").controller("appDetailsController", 
    ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


  $scope.graphData = {}


  $http.get('/api/analytics/24').then(function(data) {
    console.log('Loaded analytics data:', data);
    $scope.graphData = data.data
  })

}])
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
angular.module("app").directive("timelineGraph", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log("scope data:", scope, scope.data)
        }
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<timeline-graph data="graphData"></timeline-graph>
```

In "scope" inside the link function I can see that the data object is there but it's only populated after the call is made. So i figured out this would work and it does:

```
scope.$watch('data', function(data) {
   if(data)
     console.log('data changed:', data)
})
```

But I'd like to know if there's a better way of handling this other than putting all my code inside the watch handler.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put **all** of your code into the watch function:

```
// in your directive
scope.$watch('data', function(data) {
  if (data) {
    dataChanged();
  }
});
```

You only need to call a function to kick off the code you need to update the directive

```
// also in your directive
function dataChanged() {
  // do graphing code
}
```

Other than that, it seems like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, your code works (see below the code sample). The UI updates when the data changes, so no issues there. As @JoelCDoyle recommended, just put your code in a separate function and call it inside the $watch.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("appDetailsController", 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.graphData = [];

  $scope.init = function(){
    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(function(resp) {
      $scope.graphData = resp.data;
    })
  }  
}])
.directive("timelineGraph", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        template: '<div>"{{data}}"</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log("scope data:", scope.data)
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appDetailsController" ng-init="init()">
    <timeline-graph data-data="graphData">  </timeline-graph>
  </div>
</div>
```